# Symfony : Why I couldn't change the css style in a twig?

Tags: symfony

I recently strat working with symfony but still can't handle all its errors and problem. I couldn't modify the style of anything inside the twig!! if i use css code in the css style file or i use style attribute of a div it doesn't work!!
this is the stylesheets block :

```
  <!-- CSS -->
    {% block stylesheets %}
    <link href={{asset("css/bootstrap.min.css")}} rel="stylesheet">
    <link href={{asset("css/style2.css")}} rel="stylesheet">
    <link href={{asset("css/font-awesome.min.css")}} rel="stylesheet">
    {% endblock %}
```

and this this where i want to change the css:

```
 {% if users %}
               <div id="users_table">
                <table style="background-color: #f9f9f9;"
                       class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="color: #1b6d85"> Matricule </th>
                        <th style="color: #1b6d85"> Mot de passe </th>
                        <th style="color: #1b6d85"> Etat </th>
                        <th style="color: #1b6d85"> Action </th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for user in users %}
                    {% set iduser = user.username %}
                    {% set id = user.username %}
                    <tr><td>{{ user.username }}</td><td>{{ user.password }}</td><td>{% if user.etat==1 %}actif
                            {% elseif user.etat==0%}inactif{% endif %}</td>
                    <td>
                    <button id="activer" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
                        <a href="{{ path('act', {'iduser': iduser})}}" style="color: #ffffee;text-decoration:none">Activer</a>
                    </button>
                    <button id="desactiver" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                        <a href="{{ path('desact', {'id': id})}}" style="color: #ffffee;text-decoration: none;">Désactiver</a>
                    </button>
                    </td></tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
               </div>
            {% else %}
                    Aucun utilisateur n'a été trouvé.
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: Twig is very powerful et very simple compare to plain PHP template. Anyway, you must know that inline styling is a very bad practice because it will slow down your page generation speed. If this is only for test purpose, what do you mean by "doesn't work ?"

Comment: not really a clear question so just a wild guess: you have to copy the files to the web directory which you can do with the cli command:
php bin/console assets:install

Comment: the files are in web folder, and also in Bundle/Resources/public folder. but not all the changes in css do work ?? i mean before i start my symfony project i prepared my template in html, css and bootstrap; then i integrated it in symfony; at that time the css worked, but after that, whenever i change any thing its doesn't change or seem to work

Answer (score 0):

1st - If you change the View File (.html.twig) every time must clear the cache 
for dev:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

for prod:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

2nd - Check source code of web page in browser - is assets is good place ([Best Practice
Store your assets in the web/ directory.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html#main))

If you use bootstrap create file to adapt it for TWIG:

```
# app\config\config.yml

# (...)
form:
    resources:
        - 'YourBundle:Form:form_theme.html.twig'
```

example form_theme.html.twig:

```
    # YourBundle\Resources\views\Form\form_theme.html.twig
{% spaceless %}
{% block form_start %}
    {% set method = method|upper %}
    {% if method in ["GET", "POST"] %}
        {% set form_method = method %}
    {% else %}
        {% set form_method = "POST" %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('form-horizontal'))|trim }) %}
    <form name="{{ form.vars.name }}" method="{{ form_method|lower }}" action="{{ action }}"{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
    {% if form_method != method %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="{{ method }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_start %}

{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-group{{ errors|length > 0 ? ' has-error':'' }}">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}

{% block form_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
        {% if not compound %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' col-sm-3 control-label')|trim }) %}
        {% if label is empty %}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {% endif %}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}

{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    {% if type != 'file' %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim }) %}
    {% endif %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}

{% block textarea_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim }) %}
    <textarea {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>{{ value }}</textarea>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock textarea_widget %}

{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if required and empty_value is none and not empty_value_in_choices %}
        {% set required = false %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim }) %}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
        {% if empty_value is not none %}
            <option value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ empty_value|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% if preferred_choices|length > 0 %}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
            {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none %}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set options = choices %}
        {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
    </select>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}

{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for child in form %}
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            {{ form_widget(child) }} {{ child.vars.label }}
        </label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}

{% block form_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for error in errors %}
        <span class="help-block">{{ error.message }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}

{% block button_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock button_row %}

{% block button_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if label is empty %}
        {% set label = name|humanize %}
    {% endif %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' btn')|trim }) %}
    <button type="{{ type|default('button') }}" {{ block('button_attributes') }}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</button>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock button_widget %}

{% block submit_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('submit') %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('btn-success'))|trim }) %}
    {{ block('button_widget') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock submit_widget %}
```

Comment: why shall i use such a file?!! the bootstrap css workes pretty good, but at a certain moment my own css stop working: whenever i change a class or anything it doesn't work